# Java simple class extend case

Tags: java

The ACM libray contains the class RandomGenerator. One uses the class like this:

```
private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

//now, use rgen
```

getInstance() is static

I am trying to extend that class but I fail to understand how.

Here is my code:

```
public class RandomGeneratorwithStrings extends RandomGenerator
{
    public String get_random_string(int characters)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
private RandomGeneratorwithStrings rgen = RandomGeneratorwithStrings.getInstance();
```

I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from RandomGenerator to RandomGeneratorwithStrings.`

If I call it like this:

```
private RandomGeneratorwithStrings rgen = 
(RandomGeneratorwithStrings) RandomGeneratorwithStrings.getInstance();
```

I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: acm.util.RandomGenerator cannot be cast to RandomGeneratorwithStrings`

Comment: do something likewise, RandomGeneratorwithStrings rgen = (RandomGenerator) RandomGeneratorwithStrings.getInstance();

Comment: explicit casting needed which will cast into child type

Comment: @vishal gajera: Doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RandomGeneratorwithStrings extends RandomGenerator {

private static RandomGeneratorwithStrings instance = new RandomGeneratorwithStrings();

public static RandomGeneratorwithStrings getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public String get_random_string(int characters) {
    // ...
    return "Merry Christmass";
}
```

}

then u can use RandomGeneratorwithStrings like RandomGenerator (然后，你就可以像使用RandomGenerator一样使用RandomGeneratorwithStrings了):

```
RandomGeneratorwithStrings rgen = RandomGeneratorwithStrings.getInstance();
System.out.println(rgen.nextInt());
System.out.println(rgen.get_random_string(1));
```

(上面错误的原因在于)：
RandomGeneratorwithStrings继承了RandomGenerator，所以，父类RandomGenerator无法强转为子类RandomGeneratorwithStrings，而子类RandomGeneratorwithStrings可以向上转为父类RandomGenerator。

Comment: 上面错误的原因在于 and other chinese text doesn't help any non-Chinese-speaking people. It would be helpful to use English text only on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Because `RandomGeneratorwithStrings.getInstance();` calls the static method `getInstance()` method from inherited class which is `RandomGenerator`. Remember static methods not overridden so whenever you execute `getInstance()` method you are calling the method from the `RandomGenerator` which returns `RandomGenerator` generator Object. So when you assign it to your Custom Class that extends `RandomGenerator` you are [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) it.

Comment: Merry Christmass and thanks for the answer. I get: `java.lang.ClassCastException: acm.util.RandomGenerator cannot be cast to RandomGeneratorwithStrings`

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth: If you have any idea how I can solve my problem I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: @StackXZ - It depends on what `RandomGenerator.getInstance()` does.  If all you're trying to do is add a helper method (`get_random_string()`), I'd suggest just doing something like `class RandomStringGenerator() { private final RandomGenerator rng; RandomStringGenerator(RandomGenerator rng) { this.rng = rng; } String getString(int num) { ... } }`.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth: Thanks, unfortunately this is a school project and we are asked to extend the class. Here is the source of RandomGenerator: https://github.com/shilad/acm/blob/master/src/acm/util/RandomGenerator.java

Comment: The first part of the answer is good, but the downcast is wrong- its not a matter of how to cast it, you just cant cast because the static metod creates the parnt class, not the child

Answer (score 0):

I would enforce the *"Composition over inheritance"* practices.

```
public class RandomStringGenerator {
    private RandomGenerator randomGenerator;
    public String getRandomString(int chars) {
        //...
    }
}
```

From my point of view, it doesn't have too much sense to extend `RandomGenerator` since you won't benefit from polymorphism (with inheritance you would have to cast `RandomGenerator`to `RandomStringGenerator`, since `getRandomString` is not defined in the superclass.